# Java TIMED_WAITING and Tomcat server not responsing

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, jstack

Hi I have an application which sometimes responds to requests but sometimes doest recieve request on the given port. This appears to be a capacity issue as traffic has increased. Now I can't tell what is making in choke and since they are very many parameters to adjust, i decided to look at thread dump from jstack.

The output wasn't very helpful as it just showed several threads in the TIMED_WAIT state but the stacktrace isn't long enough to show me what part of my code is triggering this issue.

> "pool-135-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00000000427a8800 nid=0x7833 waiting on condition [0x00007fd2b22a3000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>           - parking to wait for  <0x00000006a25a5458> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
>           at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>           - None
>
> "pool-134-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x000000004169d800 nid=0x7832 waiting on condition [0x00007fd2b23a4000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>           - parking to wait for  <0x00000006a2524030> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
>           at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>           - None
>
> "pool-133-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x000000004169c800 nid=0x7831 waiting on condition [0x00007fd2b24a5000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>           - parking to wait for  <0x00000006a25045d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
>           at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>           - None

It doesn't even appear to be waiting for the same resource.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would look elsewhere.   This is just waiting to run another task of a scheduled executor (think cron job)

Comment: So in your opinion there is nothing wrong with the threads states and the casue of tomcat not processing requests is due to something else? If that is the case any pointers where i can begin looking as i have already increased the maxThread in tomcat.

Comment: The threads there are idle just waiting for a scheduled task's time to be up.  For instance if I submit a task to run once every 10 seconds, the time it's spent waiting for the 10 seconds to tick, it will sit on that queue.  So I don't think anything is moving slowly because of that

Comment: To answer your second question, you need more data/evidence as to what is wrong.  No one here can help you aside from blind speculation.  Try to get more from the thread-dump.